# One to one relationship while doing CRUD (create part)

Tags: php, laravel, crud, one-to-one

I am having some trouble doing a one to one relationship with user_info table and userImage table. When I try to upload my image, it didn't save into my database and it user_id is 0. I managed to successfully do a one to many and one to one relationship in the past but not with CRUD together. Can anyone help me? Best to give me some example for me to refer or advice on what should I do. Thanks in advance

Here are my current codes:
createController:

```
public function create1(){

    return view('create1');
}

public function store1(Request $request){
     $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

 $user_info = Session::get('data');
      $UserImage = new UserImage($request->input()) ;


if($request->hasFile('input_img')) {

$file = $request->file('input_img');

$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $UserImage->userImage = $fileName ;
        $UserImage = UserImage::create(['file' => $request->file('input_img')]);
        $UserImage->user_infos()->associate($user_info);
    }

    $UserImage->save() ;

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

HomeController(this is where I print out my information)

```
public function getInfo($id) {

  $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('test',compact('data','data3'));
```

blade.php (how I show the image in view)

```
 @foreach ($data3 as $object9)
 <img width="100" height="100" src="{!! $object9->userImage!!}">
    @endforeach
```

UserImage model(in table I used binary format to store in DB)

```
    class UserImage extends Eloquent
    {
            protected $fillable = array('userImage','user_id');
        public function user_infos() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\user_info', 'user_id', 'id');
        }

class user_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Email', 'Name');
    protected $table = user_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        public function UserImages() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserImage','user_id');
    }
}
```

create1.blade.php(this is how I upload the image)

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        {{  csrf_field()  }}


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input data-preview="#preview" name="input_img" type="file" id="imageInput">
            <img class="col-sm-6" id="preview"  src="" ></img>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out [Laravel relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) to clean up that code and simplify a lot of steps.

Change this line

```
$UserImage->user_infos()->associate($user_info);
```

For this

```
$UserImage->user_id = $user_info;
```

Take in mind that you're overriding the value of `$UserImage` inside that method.

Comment: Hi  Lloople, tks for replying but could you tell me more on which part I am doing wrong? Because after changing to your code, the image saved into database is till blank and so is the user_id