# Example of CRUD with one to one relationship and image upload laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud, one-to-one

I am having trouble understanding and knowing how to create a one to one relationship with CRUD and file upload together, is it possible to give me a simple example on how to do it? Because when I tried to do it, for some reason my `id` and `user_id` doesn't match at all

Example, in `user_info` table (jack with id 1) has one `userImage` table(image uploaded with a user_id = 1).

This is the part that I am having trouble with in my controller:

```
public function store1(Request $request){
     $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

   $user_info = Session::get('data');
      $UserImage = new UserImage($request->input()) ;


         if($file = $request->hasFile('input_img')) {
            $file = $request->file('input_img');
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images' ;
            $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
            $UserImage->userImage = $fileName ;
            $UserImage = UserImage::create(['file' => $request->file('input_img')]);
            $UserImage->user_infos()->associate($user_info);
        }

        $UserImage->save() ;
        //dd($UserImage);

        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Comment: It would probably be more beneficial if you post your code so we can point out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: CRUD operations are usually referred to in the context of persisting or manipulating a persisted single entity / instance. Relations aren't considered part of basic CRUD.

Comment: @fubar I have created another question just now (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902201/one-to-one-relationship-while-doing-crud-create-part) but I thought that maybe I need to learn more about it so I posted this question here.

Comment: @marekful but is it possible to do a relationship together with CRUD? Like for example I am trying to add a new entry in but I need it to link back to the user after creating

Answer (score 1):

Sample of one to one relationship. I wish it can help you.

Example of table of Column of `user` table:

- id
- name
- email
- password

Example of table of Column of `userimage` table:

- id
- user_id
- image_link
- uploaded

**User Model**

```
public function userImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(App\UserImage::class);
}
```

**UserImage Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(App\User::class);
}
```

**CRUD in controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $user = new App\User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->save();
        $user->userImage->create([
                'image_link'         => $request->image,
                'uploaded'         => $request->date,
            ]);
        return back();
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
        $user = App\User::find($id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->save();

        $user->userImage->image_link = $request->image;
        $user->userImage->uploaded = $request->date;
        $user->userImage->save();

        return back();
}

public function destroy($id)
{
        $user = App\User::find($id)->delete();

        return back();

}
```

Comment: tks for the quick reply, just some question, 1. shouldn't User model use belong to instead of hasOne. 2. when defining relationship in this case, is there a need to even use the associate function?

Comment: Yes, I show you the basic hasone relationship. Just experiment and explore the playground of laravel relatioship and also you need to Learn about elequent query.

Comment: I see thank you for your reply, but what I don't understand is how can you link back with user_info together with userImage  in the controller? Like could you explain more on that part

Answer (score 0):

Create a foreign key in your user_info table referencing userImage table.
Create unique constraint on the foreign key.

Comment: tks for the reply, but is there a need to use the associate function for it after defining that?